# T SQL query to find records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table similar to this

```
ID   TestID   AdddressID Value  TestDate    Case   Investigation 
1      12        140      15    11/7/2005   Open     Open
1      13        140      19    10/9/2005   Open     Open
```

If the ID has **two** address ID records I want this to show as

```
ID   AdddressID  Status 
1      140      New S&A
```

My report should Not show if I get same address again 3 or more

But If I get a new address ID 155 in future I want Latest record and My report be

```
ID    AdddressID  Status 
1       155      New A
```

Also Again if I get again address ID 140(after 155) I don't want ID to show

```
ID   TestID   AdddressID     Status
 1      12       140          
 1      13       140           New S&A
 1      14       155           New A
 1      15       140          Don't select this record
```

Comment: Requirements unclear.  You want only the latest `AddressID` to show, unless there are 3 or more instances of that address?  Then nothing shows?  And where does the `Status` come from?

Comment: Try writing the query and show us which part you're having trouble with.

Comment: If a ID has two same address id's I want to select the record and show status (New column) as "NewS&A". If the same address id is repeated I don't want to show the report. But If I get again with different address id I want to select the record with latest addressed and Status as 'New A'

Comment: Hope it's clear now. Else I have to change my script and post

Comment: test ID increments each time it seems, but the dates aren't in order....

Comment: Yes test id increment's but we aren't selecting Test id or dates in output. or ignore date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
SELECT ID, AddressID, CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 1 THEN 'New A'
                           ELSE 'New S&A'
                      END as [Status]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID, AddressID
HAVING COUNT(1) < 3
```

This will only display ID, Address combinations that occur less than 3 times:

> My report should Not show if I get same address again 3 or more

Remove the `HAVING...` if you want to see those.

**Edit: if you just want to see the latest address change, use `MAX()` in a subquery to ensure you only see the latest addressID per ID**

```
SELECT a.ID, a.AddressID, CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 1 THEN 'New A'
                               ELSE 'New S&A'
                          END as [Status]
FROM YourTable a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(AddressID) AddressID, ID 
      FROM YourTable  
      GROUP BY ID) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.AddressID = b.AddressID
GROUP BY a.ID, a.AddressID
HAVING COUNT(1) < 3
```

Comment: Well done. I had not seen your solution before posting mine. Both very similar - I guess great minds think a like ;)

Comment: Thanks but it's showing 'New A' for the records with same address id. I want 'new A' if the record has different address id. Also the record should not be selected if I have 3 or more records with same address id.

Comment: @Hanu I think I somewhat follow you, but could you add example table data to your question like Alan did in his answer?  Then add example output from that, and make sure it covers all the scenarios you mentioned.  It's easy to get to the single row you show in your question but it's hard to understand these other requirements without seeing examples.  Side note, I won't be back online until tomorrow but I'll check back if you still need help.

Comment: @AaronDietz This is woking but what's happening is  if a record has 2 addressid's 140 and one adressid 155 it's giving me result as id 1 140 'news&A' again 1 155 ''New A but I want only new 155 address id

Comment: @Hanu I added an edit.  This will make sure you only show the latest addressID for each ID.  So for `ID=1` you will only see `addressID = 155 Status = 'New A'`

Answer (score 1):

This seams pretty simple.

```
-- sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#yourtable') is not null drop table #yourtable;
create table #yourtable
(
  ID int,
  TestId int,
  AddressID int,
  [Value] int,
  TestDate date,
  [Case] varchar(20),
  Investigation varchar(20)
);
insert #yourtable values
(1, 12, 140, 15, '11/7/2005','Open','Open'),
(1, 13, 140, 19, '10/9/2005','Open','Open'),
(1, 14, 155, 19, '10/9/2005','Open','Open');

-- solution
SELECT
  ID,
  AddressID,
  [Status] = CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN 'New A' WHEN 2 THEN 'New S&A ' END
FROM #yourtable
GROUP BY ID, AddressID;
```

**Results**

```
ID          AddressID   Status
----------- ----------- --------
1           140         New S&A 
1           155         New A
```

Comment: This is working Alan Thanks but I have to do some tweaks that's okay but anyway thanks for the idea. But one more small thing. I will update question